# How to clone an scikit-learn estimator including its data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am attempting to perform a partial fit of on an naive-bayes estimator but also retain a copy of the estimator prior to the partial fit. sklearn.base.clone only clones an estimators parameters, not it's data, so is not useful in this case. Performing a partial fit on the clone only uses the data added during the partial fit, since the clone is effectively empty.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

model = MultinomialNB()
fit_model = model.fit(np.array(X),np.array(y))
fit_model2 = model.partial_fit = (np.array(Z),np.array(w)),np.unique(y))
```

In the above example fit_model and fit_model2 will be the same since they both point to the same object. I would like to retain the original copy unaltered. My workaround is to pickle the original and load it into a new object to perform a partial fit on. Like this:

```
model = MultinomialNB()
fit_model = model.fit(np.array(X),np.array(y))

import pickle
with open('saved_model', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([model], f)

with open('saved_model', 'rb') as f:
    [model2] = pickle.load(f) 

fit_model2 = model2.partial_fit(np.array(Z),np.array(w)),np.unique(y))
```

Also I can completely refit with the new data each time, but since I need to perform this thousands of times I'm trying to find something more efficient.

Comment: Did you try `copy` or `deepcopy`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. `model.fit()` returns the model itself (the same object). So you don't have to assign it to a different variable as it's just aliasing.
2. You can use `deepcopy` to copy the object in a similar way to what loading a pickled object does.

So if you do something like:

```
from copy import deepcopy

model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(y))

model2 = deepcopy(model)

model2.partial_fit(np.array(Z),np.array(w)), np.unique(y))
# ...
```

`model2` will be a distinct object, with the copied parameters of `model`, including the "trained" parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: after model2.partial_fit(), model will also reflect the update. Instead of copy, use deepcopy

Answer (score 2):

```
from copy import deepcopy

model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(y))

model2 = deepcopy(model)

weight_vector_model = array(model.coef_[0])
weight_vector_model2 = array(model2.coef_[0])

model2.partial_fit(np.array(Z),np.array(w)), np.unique(y))

weight_vector_model = array(model.coef_[0])
weight_vector_model2 = array(model2.coef_[0])
```

model and model2 are now completely different objects. partial_fit() on model2 will have no impact on model. The two weight vectors are same after deepcopy but differ after partial_fit() on model2

Answer (score -2):

I tried **deepcopy** but I got a leak of memory when deleting the variables. I found out at the documentation that it is recomended to use **clone** instead
[sklearn.base.clone](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html)

```
from sklearn.base import clone
model2 = clone(model)
```

Comment: Note that in the docs, it states that `sklearn.base.clone` does not copy data, and thus yields a model that is not fitted.